# I am a program, need I say more?

Tags: riddle

> this riddle is easy - that *m*uch i can say,
>   *p*le*a*se follow alo*n*g, right this way.
>
> before we start - I must warn you all,
>   *qu*estions of any sort, well, uhh, not allowed.
>
> (almost) all of these words are meaningless - the itali*x* you must check,
>   i don't take any blame, for ni*x*on and his wreck.
>
> i really can't to say any more,
>   i want to *ge*t hats, that's all this is *f*or.
>
> do you think i'm so *d*u*m*b, i would give it all away?
>   i*f* you give me some rep, m*a*ybe someday.
>
> rot13 - that won't be of use,
>  
>   in my other stack, you may fin*d* some clues.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Is the answer:

> adobeillustrator ? 
>  I used F12 to check all italic chars -> mpanquxxgefdmfad, then deciphered it by rot14 -> adobeillustrator

Answer (score 4):

Since you told us that you are a program. I wrote a short program as well.

> https://jsfiddle.net/yq75c8mj/2/
>  The riddle text was copied into an online markdown converter so that the text can be easily parsed.

```
var inputStr = `> this riddle is easy - that *m*uch i can say,\
> *p*le*a*se follow alo*n*g, right this way.
>
> before we start - I must warn you all,\
> *qu*estions of any sort, well, uhh, not allowed.
>
> (almost) all of these words are meaningless - the itali*x* you must check,\
> i don't take any blame, for ni*x*on and his wreck.
>
> i really can't to say any more,\
> i want to *ge*t hats, that's all this is *f*or.
>
> do you think i'm so *d*u*m*b, i would give it all away?\
> i*f* you give me some rep, m*a*ybe someday.
>
> rot13 - that won't be of use,\
> in my other stack, you may fin*d* some clues.`;

var italicText = inputStr.match(/\*\w+\*/g);
var newarr = Object.keys(italicText)
    .map((key) => italicText[key])
    .map((el) => el.replace(/\*/g, ''))
  .reduce((acc, currVal) => acc + currVal, "")

var solved = rotateCharsWithOffset(newarr, 14)

console.log(solved);
document.write(solved);
alert(solved);

function rotateCharsWithOffset(str, offset) {
  return str.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,function(c){return String.fromCharCode((c<="Z"?90:122)>=(c=c.charCodeAt(0)+offset)?c:c-26);});
}
```

Comment: That's super awesome!